# CSS remove bullet points on internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a bullet points issue in Internet Explorer. I already tried to remove the doubled displayed bullets in ie, but I can't figured out why they always be displayed. In Internet Explorer 11 it shows my own icon (a green hook) and the generated icon from the browser. I want to keep the green hook and would like remove the gray bullets. Please take a look [here](http://www.deutsch-vietnamesisch-dolmetscher.com/).
If you don't have Internet Explorer, please take a look at my [image: screenshot]. Thanks!

My CSS Code to generate the bullets:

```
ul,li, .nav ul, .nav li {
    list-style:none;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position:inside;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.content ul{list-style:none;margin-left:0;padding-left:0em;text-indent:0em;}
.content ul li:before{
    content:'';
    background:url(http://www.deutsch-vietnamesisch-dolmetscher.com/i/haken-gruen.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:left center;
    padding:0 0 0 20px;
    margin:0 0px 0 0;
    list-style:none;
    white-space:normal
}
.content ul {padding: 0 0 0 15px;}
.content ul li ul {padding: 0 0 0 15px;}
.content ul li.list:before{background: none;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to load the CSS code lazy with JavaScript loadCSS from scottjehl. His framework loads a CSS file asynchronously. Please search for loadCSS from [c]@scottjehl, Filament Group, Inc.

Comment: New version 2016: https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS
Old Version example 2014: https://martinwolf.org/blog/2014/12/load-css-asynchronously-with-loadcss

Answer (score 3):

The bug comes from pagespeed optimization. When I add the css code directly before the closed body, then the unwanted bullets appear. If I embedded the css file directly in the head, then everythings theem to be ok. I hope someone need this solution too.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please remove `list-style-position: inside;` from line 3 of your CSS file. It will remove bullets from list items.
2. To remove bullets and tick marks from social buttons, you need to use background image wisely and target specific pseudo element. Please read about it in CSS specification to understand it better.

```css
.socializm ul li:before {
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: If you want I can help directly on page. There are so many times you wrote `list-style: none;` in `li` and `ul`. That might be the issue. I checked inspecting element and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same trouble of nickName: I just applied a speed optimization appending static resources at the end of body tag (couldn't make dynamic ones) and IE11 doesn't render (some of) the LIs correctly. When I moved the

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul li {
        list-style: none;
    }
</style>
```

part to the header, everything restarted working correctly.

Comment: After four hours of debugging and searching, this is the only answer that fixed the same issue for me. Lists that start as hidden with `display: none` and then shown with Jquery will always ignore list-style and show bullets in IE. Adding this inline style was the only fix, however has generated heaps of problems elsewhere in the app. This bug has been in IE since 2007 from what I can gather.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you applying `list-style: none;` to the parent and not the child `li`. Your also applying it to the pseudo-class `:before`. You just need it on the actual list-item itself.

**You code is:**

```
.content ul{list-style:none;margin-left:0;padding-left:0em;text-indent:0em;}
.content ul li:before{
    content:'';
    background:url(http://www.deutsch-vietnamesisch-dolmetscher.com/i/haken-gruen.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:left center;
    padding:0 0 0 20px;
    margin:0 0px 0 0;
    list-style:none;
    white-space:normal
}
```

Your code SHOULD be:

```
.content ul{margin-left:0;padding-left:0em;text-indent:0em;}
.content ul li:before{
    content:'';
    background:url(http://www.deutsch-vietnamesisch-dolmetscher.com/i/haken-gruen.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:left center;
    padding:0 0 0 20px;
    margin:0 0px 0 0;
    white-space:normal;
}
/* -- added -- */
.content ul li{ list-style: none; }
```

Comment: I don't know why it does not help me. Do I run in cache issues?

Comment: Try clearing your cache or pressing Ctrl+F5 to do a hard refresh?

Comment: Yes, I always do both, but it does not help.

Answer (score -1):

**Css:**

```
  li {list-style: none;}
```

you need to apply, use just tag `li` and that's it. The problem is solved