# Cannot remove bullets from list on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a `ul` list and I cannot make Internet Explorer stop showing bullets on the `li`. I tried every way I could found on web, but they are still there.

**HTML code:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="/mydomain.com/en">EN</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/mydomain.com/fr">FR</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS code:**

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    // tried also list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    // tried also list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

**UPDATE WITH THE SOLUTION**

There was also some other CSS rules which was crossed out and they should not applied on the website. One of them was:

```
li:before {
    content: '\25A0';
}
```

As I said, this CSS was crossed out in the developer tools, in both Chrome, Mozilla and IE. However, when I added in my stylesheet the `content:none`, the bullets just disappeared. Probably a bug on IE that uses the content that are crossed out?

Comment: First thing to do when it comes to a browser issue: Which version(s) of IE? Old IE is notorious for being, ahem, "special".

Comment: @SamHH My mistake :) It is on 11.0.22

Comment: Try to put also `list-style-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7);` ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356311/internet-explorer-11-ignores-list-stylenone-on-the-first-load))

Comment: @AndreaGhidini Unfortunately, nothing. I added it to both ul and li.

Comment: Is there some rule that takes precedence (maybe some css included only in IE)? Did you try with `!important`? What does the dev tools tell about the `li` and `ul` elements?

Comment: Tried it also with `!important`. And in the developer tool, the rule is not crossed.

Comment: Are you using an external stylesheet or is your CSS embedded or inline?

Comment: @Michael_B It is a css file calling on the head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to replicate the problem in IE11. I tested using external, embedded and inline styles, and in all cases the bullets were removed normally and without any issue.

However, this is a documented problem.

It appears to be a bug in IE11. Some have found a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609531/css-remove-bullet-points-on-internet-explorer) by moving style rules from the external stylesheet to the `<head>` section of the document (i.e., using embedded styles). Others have found a [solution with the `list-style-image` property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356311/internet-explorer-11-ignores-list-stylenone-on-the-first-load).

- [CSS remove bullet points on internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609531/css-remove-bullet-points-on-internet-explorer)
- [Internet Explorer 11 ignores list-style:none on the first load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356311/internet-explorer-11-ignores-list-stylenone-on-the-first-load)

Comment: Added on the `<head>` directly in `<style>` tags, but still the same issue. I don't know what to say.

Comment: Can you post a link to a live site or demo?

Comment: It is behind a coming soon page and I cannot open it for the next week.

Comment: Just saw that I have this error on the console: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL` for the `list-style-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRA‌​A7);`

Comment: Unfortunately (like I mentioned), I am unable to replicate the problem. Everything is working fine here on IE 11. But go through the link references I posted. There are various different solutions that have worked for others.

Comment: This problem in IE11 seems to pop "randomly" for me, i solved it once for all by adding basic list-style-type:none inline instead than in external css